# Send PHP code through form in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have a wordpress blog **theme settings page** using functions.php
How can i send php codes thro functions.php?

Thank u!

Comment: What do you mean with "PHP codes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can ***NOT*** insert/send php code to **functions.php** from wordpress's ***theme settings page***; if it was possible, they would have hacked into wordpress easily :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can send php code through functions.php, however it's not recommended at all. Sounds like you need to come up with a better solution that won't get your site hacked.

Comment: He needs to add/insert/send the code through admin that is theme settings page